# как добавить к стандартной проверки валидации свое свойство проверки?Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
как к примеру сделать чтобы в title не могло быть слова 'Доллар' ?

т.е если пользователь введет название POST в котором содержится слово Доллар вывело такую же стандартную ошибку только с надписью слово Доллар запрещено писать

$request->validate([
            'author_id' => 'required|integer|exists:authors,id',
            'title' => 'required|max:255|string'
            
        ]);
```

Comment: Вам нужны валидаторы in и not_in. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-not-in

Comment: это если ввести только 'Доллар' а если разбавить с другим словом это не сработает